# Loading data using storage Write API gives quota limit error also chunking data

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery

I'm trying to use BigQuery storage write API https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/write-api, in this function, data is a list of serialized string using protobuf https://protobuf.dev/getting-started/pythontutorial/ .
To do not reach the quota limit for a row (of 10MB) I chunk the data using:

```
  def chunk_list(data):

        chunk = []
        chunks = []

        for item in data:
            #size in bytes
            single_item_size = len(item)

            #we check dimension for serialized item, if too big it is discarded
            if single_item_size > MAX_BYTE_ROW_SIZE:
                logger.warning(f"Item {item} too big for being inserted, discarding it")
                continue

            #if adding this item chunks became too big we save the chunk as it is
            #ad we start the new chunk using item
            new_chunk_size = sum([len(x) for x in chunk]) + single_item_size
            if new_chunk_size > MAX_BYTE_ROW_SIZE:
                chunks.append(chunk)
                chunk = [item]
            #if the chunk is not too big we append this item
            else:
                chunk.append(item)

        #last chunk
        if chunk:
            chunks.append(chunk)

        return chunks
```

All the chunks are sent in a loop like

```
        chunks = chunk_list(data)

        instance = proto_class()
        for i, chunk in enumerate(chunks):
            #this is for an append rows stream
            append_rows_stream = get_append_rows_stream(instance)
            proto_rows = types.ProtoRows()
            proto_rows.serialized_rows = chunk
            request = types.AppendRowsRequest()
            proto_data = types.AppendRowsRequest.ProtoData()
            proto_data.rows = proto_rows
            request.proto_rows = proto_data
            request.offset = 0
            append_rows_stream.send(request)
            append_rows_stream.close()
```

as it is written in google's tutorials. The Write stream is commited after the end of all this loop.

Using that I'm still getting erros like: API limit exceeded: Message before conversion exceeds max row limit, limit: 20971520 actual: 48639135

I tried the chunking function and seems to work well, I can't figure out the problem.

I tried to use different sizes for the chunks but I'm still getting the error, I can't find the issue unfortunately. I expected to avoid quota size limit error using chunks